# how to save file opened by GhostPCL

Tags: c#, asp.net, ghostscript

I have a pcl file in my project. I am using GhostPCL to convert it to pcl. I have opened my pcl file through gsPcl.exe. It opens the file in a window.now I have to save this file as pdf. please describe how to do this?  my code is given below-

```
  public void convertToPdf()
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\vivek.mishra\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Ghost\Ghost\gpcl.exe"; //not the full application path
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = @"E:\print\print.pcl";

        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not building the command line string correctly.

Once you have built the command line string correctly, simply pass it:

```
Process.Start(strCommand);
```

Building the command line depends on what you want to do.

From [How to use Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm):

### Invoking Ghostscript

This document describes how to use the command line Ghostscript client. Ghostscript is also used as a general engine inside other applications (for viewing files for example). Please refer to the documentation for those applications for using Ghostscript in other contexts.

The command line to invoke Ghostscript is essentially the same on all systems, although the name of the executable program itself may differ among systems. For instance, to invoke Ghostscript on unix-like systems type:

gs [options] {filename 1} ... [options] {filename N} ...
Here are some basic examples. The details of how these work are described below.

To view a file:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH document.pdf
```

You'll be prompted to press return between pages.

To convert a figure to an image file:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=tiger.png tiger.eps
```

To render the same image at 300 dpi:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -r300 -sOutputFile=tiger_300.png tiger.eps
```

To render a figure in grayscale:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=figure.png figure.pdf
```

To rasterize a whole document:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pgmraw -r150 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile='paper-%00d.pgm' paper.ps
```

There are also a number of utility scripts for common to convert a PostScript document to PDF:

```
ps2pdf file.ps
```

The output is saved as file.pdf.

There are other utility scripts besides ps2pdf, including pdf2ps, ps2epsi, pdf2dsc, ps2ascii, ps2ps and ps2ps2. These just call Ghostscript with the appropriate (if complicated) set of options. You can use the 'ps2' set with eps files.

Ghostscript is capable of interpreting PostScript, encapsulated PostScript (EPS), DOS EPS (EPSF), and Adobe Portable Document Format (PDF). The interpreter reads and executes the files in sequence, using the method described under "File searching" to find them.

The interpreter runs in interactive mode by default. After processing the files given on the command line (if any) it reads further lines of PostScript language commands from the primary input stream, normally the keyboard, interpreting each line separately. To quit the interpreter, type "quit". The -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE options in the examples above disable the interactive prompting. The interpreter also quits gracefully if it encounters end-of-file or control-C.

The interpreter recognizes many options. An option may appear anywhere in the command line, and applies to all files named after it on the line. Many of them include "=" followed by a parameter. The most important are described in detail here. Please see the reference sections on options and devices for a more complete listing.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert a PCL file to PCL ? Really ?

You need to specify a number of command line options to Ghostscript, in your case you will need the -sDEVICE and -sOutputFile switches. Try reading the documentation.